# Get Perforce to auto-checkout changed files, similar to TortiseSVN?

Tags: version-control, tortoisesvn, perforce

I'm coming from TortiseSVN, where if you save a file over an existing revision it automatically gets checked out and locked for you.

However, in Perforce I have to manually checkout the file before saving it.

Is it possible to make Perforce work more like SVN in this regard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With modern versions of Perforce this is reasonably straightforward:

1. Modify your workspace options to enable the 'allwrite' option, which specifies that you want files on your workspace to be left writable when 'p4 sync' syncs them.
2. 'p4 sync #none' followed by 'p4 sync' to refresh your workspace and get all your files into writable mode.
3. Before you submit, use 'p4 reconcile -aed' to have Perforce figure out which files you have modified, and open them for add/edit/delete as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but Step 2 seems a major slowdown of workflow if the repo is large, and a risk in local testability if breaking changes from team are synced over.

Comment: If you are working with the P4V GUI, there is a Reconcile Offline Work command that can do this.  My only issue with that is that it shows all files not in the depot, not just the ones that have changed.  That is usually not useful to me as I have a pile of object files in the same folder as the source.  What is needed is basically 'p4 reconcile -e'.  Possible via command line, but not via GUI.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many permutations to this question, but the following worked for me.  My apologies if it does not work for you (then we must have slightly different setups)

- I am running VS2019 and P4V 2021
- First I installed Helix Visual Client to VS

  - From VS
  - Extension => Manage Extensions => Visual Studio Marketplace
  - Search for: P4VS - Helix Plugin for Visual Studio
  - Install
- Create VS connection to the Repos

  - From VS
  - File => Clone Repository => Helix Core Server (click link under "Browse a Repository")
  - Complete the connection information

    - Can be obtained by opening Perforce
    - Connection => Open Connections

After completing the above, whenever I edit a non-checked out file, I get a prompt "Do you wish to checkout the file"

Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, from my research and these other poster's answers, it seems that the answer is "no." I'd prefer to not have to do a hack to achieve auto-checking out files on save.

Plastic (both Gluon and SCM) also support the auto-checkout feature, which is very convenient.