Sync only files that are changed/edited on my local system with the latest on TOT
I have a p4 client where I have made changes to many files. I don't remember what all those files were and which one was changed. I need a command to force sync only those files that are not in sync with my depot. How do I do that?
What I tried
p4 sync -f

This command is updating all files on my repo.

Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36412213/924827

Yes I have seen this and this is where I lost it. "'p4 sync #none' followed by 'p4 sync' to refresh your workspace and get all your files into writable mode." I just  want the chaged files to be synced!!!

There's a specific command for this:
p4 clean

See p4 help clean for more information.  It follows the same logic as p4 reconcile, using checksum comparison to identify differing files, but instead of opening them (preparing the local changes to be submitted to the depot), it force-syncs them (permanently discarding the local changes).

I use p4v and I checkout everything and then I 'revert unchanged files'.The commands displayed in the log are:
p4 edit C:\Users\myuser\src\MY_WORKSPACE\...  #(the path points to the location of the workspace in my machine)
p4 revert -a C:\Users\myuser\src\MY_WORKSPACE\...

This should leave only the edited files checked out
